# Create correct folder structure from files "folder\file"

Tags: command-line, bash

I have extracted a .zip file which was generated in Windows.

Now I have a list of files like:

```
fileonrootfolder.txt
otherfileonrootfolder.txt
folder1\
folder1\filex.xyz
folder1\filey.xyz
folder1\filez.xyz
folder2\filex.xyz
folder2\filey.abc
....
```

Here the backslash \ is a part of the filename. The files are all stored in the same root folder. (As all know here, Linux uses a slash not a backslash as folder separator)

Please provide a bash command to generate the correct folder structure and move the files accordingly. (The folder hierarchy just consists of one level).

Thanks.

Additional info:

```
$ lsb_release -a 
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 23.10
Release:    23.10
Codename:   mantic
$ uname -a
Linux abc 6.5.0-13-generic #13-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Fri Nov  3 12:16:05 UTC 2023 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: I don't know which tool you have used to "unzip" the files, but the Linux tools will create the folder structure correctly without the backslash problem. Please, retry with an Ubuntu tool like the `unzip` command line or the Gnome **Archive Manager** GUI. What is the version of your Ubuntu system? Please [edit] your question to add more details.

Comment: @FedKad.  I have tried (1) using right click "Extract File" in the Ubuntu folder view, AND (2) the 'unzip compressed.zip' command from the bash.    Both with the same result. Seems to be a feature of the .zip file.

Comment: Please, see this: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/377986/looking-for-a-script-to-convert-a-filename-with-backslashes-into-a-directory-str

Comment: Thanks @FedKad   solution at your given link worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't really understand how this happened, but if you really have file names containing literal backslashes, this should convert them to the expected directory structure:

```bash
for file in *\\*; do 
  newName=${file/\\/\/}
  if [[ "$file" =~ \\$ ]]; then 
    mkdir -p "$newName" && 
      rm "$file"
  else 
    mkdir -p "$(dirname "$newName")"
    mv -- "$file" "$newName"
  fi
done
```

#### Explanation

- `for file in *\\*`: The glob `*\\*` matches any file or directory name in the current directory whose name contains a `\`. Because the `\` is also the escape character, we need to escape it so it is treated as a literal. That's why we can't just use `*\*`.

  Then, this will iterate over all files and directories whose name contains a `\`, saving each of them as `$file`.
- `newName=${file/\\/\/}`: This will print the current file name with all `\` replaced with `/`. The escaping `\\` and `\/`) is needed since both `\` and `/` are special characters.
- `if [[ "$file" =~ \\$ ]]; then`: if this file *ends* with a `\` , so if it is supposed to be a directory.
- `mkdir -p "$newName" && rm "$file"`: create the directory and delete the file.
- `else mkdir -p "$(dirname "$newName")"`: if it isn't a directory, create the parent directory
- `mv -- "$file" "$newName"`: and move the file into it.

Answer (score 0):

Based on hint of @FedKad I could use solution from: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/377986/looking-for-a-script-to-convert-a-filename-with-backslashes-into-a-directory-str

```
for file in *\\*; do 
    dir="$(dirname -- "${file//\\/\/}")"
    filename="${file##*\\}"
    mkdir -p -- "$dir"
    mv -- "$file" "$dir"/"$filename"
done
```

Comment: This doesn't actually work in your case, sorry. It will leave you with `folder1\ ` and `folder2\ ` files. The question I answered on Unix and Linux didn't have such files.

Comment: Yes @terdon this is correct.   I have manually deleted these 'folder?\' files.  Not perfect solution. But was sufficient for my job.

Comment: I posted a solution that handles this, but the easiest thing is to just run `rm *\\` after running what is in your answer.